# fix error in string where numbers are replacing letters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to fix a string that has errors. In a string `S` is misinterpreted as `5`, `O` is misinterpreted as `0` and `I` is misinterpreted as `1`.

See the following examples.

`correct("L0ND0N") => "LONDON"`

`correct("BUDAPE5T"),"BUDAPEST"`

I have been looking at my code for ages and have no idea why it isn't working. See code below.

Can anyone see what mistake I am making?

The challenge is [taken from here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/correct-the-mistakes-of-the-character-recognition-software/train/javascript).

```
function correct(string){
    let fix = {
    "5": "S",
    "1": "I",
    "0": "O"
  }
  let strArr = string.split("");

  return strArr.map(item => {
    for(var key in fix){
      if(item === key){
        return fix[key]
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    }
  }).join('');

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a callback to String.replace which will make this task easier:

```js
function correct(str) {
    let fix = {
        "5": "S",
        "1": "I",
        "0": "O"
    };
    return str.replace(/(\d)/g, a => fix[a] || a);
}
console.log(correct("BUDAPE5T"));
```

For your original question, your for loop isn't looping, but you are returning on the first iteration of it. Change it to

```
return strArr.map(item => {
    let f;
    for(var key in fix){
        if(item === key){
            f = fix[key]
        } else {
            f = item;
        }
    }
    return f;
}).join('');
```

and it'll work too (but better go with the replace function).

Sidenote:

Superdrac is thinking the original code is working because it actually works for "L0ND0N". That is a funny "coincidence", as the `fix` object's keys get sorted like `{ '0': 'O', '1': 'I', '5': 'S' }` (at least in some browsers if not all). As you were only "looping" once, the first key could get checked and replaced correctly. With the fix I posted, every key can get replaced.

Comment: I do know there are other ways of doing this, which i really appreciate, but can you see something wrong with my code?

Comment: @Superdrac that is all the code. Maybe it is something wrong with the codewars site as the answer here works.

Comment: @RaulRodriguez Added the explanation to the answer

Comment: @Superdrac I'm not sure what you think is working with his code.

Comment: @baao did you tried his code before answering the question ?

Comment: @baao it wasn't working you're correct, and the answer you gave is perfect. dunno who down voted. Ill give the green tick when i can

Comment: @RaulRodriguez I think superdrac is a bit confused... :-)

Comment: Hum, he want this -> "L0ND0N" turn into this -> "LONDON" through the correct() function ?

Comment: @Superdrac explained this in the answer for you too

Comment: @baao Ohhhh sorry man !  I didn't even noticed this ! Thank for the explanation !